# IE Date.toLocaleTimeString().split isn't returning an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, internet-explorer

This is straight from the console in IE (Microsoft Edge 25.10):

```
greg = new Date().toLocaleTimeString().split(':')[0];
"12"
greg = new Date().toLocaleTimeString().split(':')[0]=="12";
false
```

why?

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: the 12 is the hour in my ENV, maybe it became "13" when you the executed second code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because there are two invisible characters in the string: [U-200E](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=200E) (left-to-right marks) at the beginning and end:

```
new Date().toLocaleTimeString().split(':')[0] == "\u200e12\u200e" // true
```

[`toLocaleTimeString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.tolocaletimestring) is defined [here](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-402/3.0/index.html#sup-date.prototype.tolocaletimestring) by [ECMA-402](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-402/3.0/index.html) if the browser supports ECMA-402; otherwise, it's completely up to the implementation. IE doesn't support ECMA-402 and thus it can put anything in that string it likes. Including left-to-right marks seems a bizarre thing to do, but...

Comment: wow... thanks.  looks like I've got some reading to do.  I've never even heard of this u200e you speak of

Comment: T.J: Any idea why IE does this? Chrome doesn't seem to...

Comment: @Cerbrus: Nope. :-| It seems frankly like a bizarre thing to do.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I first checked `[0].length`, which turned out to be `4`... wtf.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, there appear to be some invisible characters surrounding the numbers in that time string:

> [image]

This can be circumvented / solved by parsing the split part as integer:

```js
var part = new Date(2016, 00, 01, 10, 55, 30) // Fri Jan 01 2016 10:55:30
    .toLocaleTimeString().split(':')[0];

console.log(part);
console.log(part == "10");
console.log(parseInt(part) == 10);
```